# Error "util.inherits is not a function" when using Google Cloud platform in Nuxt 3

Tags: google-bigquery, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

**Context**

I am trying to use Google Cloud BigQuery in my Nuxt 3 application.

First, I set up a client side Nuxt plugin which I put inside `/plugins/gcConfig.client.ts`. I am authenticating the service with Application Default Credentials:

```
import { BigQuery } from "@google-cloud/bigquery";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((_nuxtApp) => {
  const bigquery = new BigQuery();

  return {
    provide: {
      bigquery: bigquery,
    },
  };
});
```

I plan to use this instance of bigquery in my app.

Using this version of BigQuery

```
"@google-cloud/bigquery": "^6.2.0",
```

Using this version of nuxt

```
nuxt@3.5.3
```

**Problem**

As soon as my app starts, the plugin runs, and I get the following warnings/errors in the browser console:

Warning:

```
chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=f068b036:16 Module "util" has been externalized for browser compatibility. 
Cannot access "util.inherits" in client code. See http://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: util.inherits is not a function
    at node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js (data-stream.js:39:6)
    at __require2 (chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=f068b036:16:50)
    at node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js (sign-stream.js:3:18)
    at __require2 (chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=f068b036:16:50)
    at node_modules/jws/index.js (index.js:2:18)
    at __require2 (chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=f068b036:16:50)
    at node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js (index.js:12:13)
    at __require2 (chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=f068b036:16:50)
    at node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js (jwtclient.js:17:18)
    at __require2 (chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=f068b036:16:50)
```

I tried to swap out `"@google-cloud/bigquery": "^6.2.0",` for `"@google-cloud/storage": "^6.11.0",` completely using the same setup, however, I got the same errors.

These errors cause my app to crash. Can someone help me?